# jQuery - check if has radio button in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if a div has radio, file, checkbox. I just complete my markup in Html. I haven't any idea about this.

```
<div id="div1">

  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Female

</div> 

<br/>

<div id="div2">

  <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="file" name="file2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
if ($('div:has(:radio)').length > 0) {
    //code for radio button
}
if ($('.div:has(:file)').length > 0) {
    //code for file
}
if ($('.div:has(:checkbox)').length > 0) {
    //code for checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('div').find('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="file"]').length > 0) {...}
```

Comment: _I want to check if a div has radio, file, checkbox_

Comment: `$('div').find('input[type="radio"]')` will return an array of elements, and if there is no radio input inside this div, the array will have zero length...

Comment: & what about _file, checkbox_ !!

Comment: `$('div').find('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="file"]')`

Comment: Try also `$('div').find(':radio,:checkbox,:file')`.. update answer not comment. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Use `has()` method and `:radio` `:checkbox` selectors, you dont need any `if()` statement, check this:

```js
$('div:has(:radio,[type=file],:checkbox)').html("This div has these inputs")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Female

</div> 

<br/>

<div id="div2">

  <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="file" name="file2">

</div>
<br>
<div id="div3">
   Other inputs div
  <input type="text" name="i1" value="test"><br>
  <input type="number" name="i2" value="12">

</div>
```

Comment: The other answer use `if()`. I dont :)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Radio check
    `if($('#div1').find(':radio').length > 0){...`

File check

`if($('#div2').find(':file').length > 0){...`

```js
if($('#div1').find(':radio').length > 0){
 console.log('div1 has radio');
}
if($('#div2').find(':file').length > 0){
 console.log('div2 has file');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Femal
</div> 
<br/>
<div id="div2">
  <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="file" name="file2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the div has any input descendents

```js
$("div").each( function() {
  var divWithInputExists = $(this).find("input").length > 0;
  console.log("Does this div has inputs -> " , divWithInputExists)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Male
  <input type="radio" name="rd1"> Femal
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2">
  <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="file" name="file2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do it one of the following ways

Using id selector

if($('#divID :radio').length)
{
   //
}
Using class selector

if($('.div-class :radio').length)
{
   //
}
Using tag name selector

if($('div :radio').length)
{
   //
}*emphasized text*
```